# Problem when running the Clip Raster by Mask Layer - Layers were not correctly generated

Tags: qgis, polygon, algorithm

I need help, this is for my Final Year Project.
Yesterday before I did something on my QGIS, I can run the mask layer but suddenly after I followed a tutorial on youtube on how to do 3D Map, I cannot run the mask layer again. I've search answers but none of them can help me. What should I do? Below is from the log messages.

```
QGIS version: 3.16.2-Hannover
QGIS code revision: f1660f9da5
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.1.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Clip raster by mask layer' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ALPHA_BAND' : False, 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/New folder/Peta/DEM/Malaysia.tif', 'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False, 'MASK' : 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/New folder/Peta/Shapefile/Batu Gajah/Shale.shp|layername=Shale', 'MULTITHREADING' : False, 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'SET_RESOLUTION' : False, 'SOURCE_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_CRS' : None, 'X_RESOLUTION' : None, 'Y_RESOLUTION' : None }

GDAL command:
gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline "C:/Users/User/Desktop/New folder/Peta/Shapefile/Batu Gajah/Shale.shp" -cl Shale -crop_to_cutline "C:/Users/User/Desktop/New folder/Peta/DEM/Malaysia.tif" C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_FQruTL/38b9353213c7499cb36cab6f30c2a177/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
Warning 1: Self-intersection at or near point 100.9829299492848 4.3754446642990406

ERROR 1: Cutline polygon is invalid.

Execution completed in 0.16 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_FQruTL/38b9353213c7499cb36cab6f30c2a177/OUTPUT.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_FQruTL/38b9353213c7499cb36cab6f30c2a177/OUTPUT.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message should give you a clue:

> ```
> Warning 1: Self-intersection at or near point 100.9829299492848 4.3754446642990406
>
> ERROR 1: Cutline polygon is invalid.
> ```

I suggest running the QGIS [Fix Geometries tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisfixgeometries) to repair the self-intersection.